# working with array(s) in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am inputting values into an array in jQuery like 1,4,7,3.  But when I am displaying the array values, it displays like 1,3,4,7.

i need like 1,4,7,3 as it is when they were inserted. This is my code.

```
var selectedValues = [];
var $ctrls = $("[id*=chkProcessRoutes] input:checkbox");
$("[id*=chkProcessRoutes] input:checked").each(function () {
    var l = parseFloat(($ctrls.index($(this))));
    var ll = parseFloat(l) + 1;
    selectedValues.push(parseFloat(ll));
});
if (selectedValues.length > 0) {
    alert("Selected Value(s): " + selectedValues.toString());
} else {
    alert("No item has been selected.");
}
```

Comment: Add the code you're working with

Comment: Provide code please.

Comment: You must show your actual code.  Questions about code here on StackOverflow MUST contain the actual code you are using so we can tell you what it is you are doing wrong.  This is not a site where we try to guess what you might be doing wrong.  We analyze your ACTUAL code.  The downvotes you've received is because you've asked a completely unclear question that really does little but waste people's time trying to understand.  Your job is to include ALL relevant information such that the smart people here can easily help you.  If you don't do that, your questions will be downvoted and closed.

Comment: Since it appears you may be new here, please read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: var selectedValues = [];            
                var $ctrls = $("[id*=chkProcessRoutes] input:checkbox");
                $("[id*=chkProcessRoutes] input:checked").each(function () {
                    var l = parseFloat(($ctrls.index($(this))));
                    var ll = parseFloat(l) + 1;
                    selectedValues.push(parseFloat(ll));                 
                });
                if (selectedValues.length > 0) {
                     alert("Selected Value(s): " + selectedValues.toString());
            } else {     alert("No item has been selected.");
            }

Comment: you can edit question. please read the link above

Comment: you are inserting as `1,3,4,7` only, because you are adding the index value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var selectedValues = $("[id*=chkProcessRoutes] input:checked").map(function () {
    return $(this).val();
});
if (selectedValues.length > 0) {
    alert("Selected Value(s): " + selectedValues.toString());
} else {
    alert("No item has been selected.");
}
```